# How do I run ignition gazebo distributed (server on one machine, GUI on another)?

Tags: gazebo-ignition, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to figure out how to run `ignition gazebo -s shapes.sdf` on one machine, and `ignition gazebo -g` on another (both hosts on the same LAN). I've found the tutorial at https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/gazebo/3.5/distributedsimulation.html, but it's pretty terse. I tried this:
`ign gazebo -s --network-role=primary --network-secondaries=1 --distributed shapes.sdf`, but it fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/bin/ign:267:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo3.rb:324:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo3.rb:310:in `parse': invalid option: --distributed (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

I'm running Citadel on Ubuntu 18.

I get the impression that the docs are a little rough. Any suggestions on where to look for more documentation or examples?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26549/how-do-i-run-ignition-gazebo-distributed-(server-on-one-machine,-gui-on-another)?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11405/rick-armstrong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11405/rick-armstrong/) on 2021-10-25**:
Bump. Has nobody tried this?

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-02-18**:
Oh dear, is this still ongoing? Any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Had the same problem and landed here googling for a solution. Eventually I found out that you have to set an environment variable to tell the GUI which host and user to connect to.

See [Gazebo environment variables](https://gazebosim.org/api/transport/11.0/envvars.html).

My Setup:

- Gazebo Fortress
- The simulation is running on machine 1, the GUI is running on machine 2.
- Both machines are in the same subnet (192.168.0.xyz).

Machine 1 (simulation):

- user: user1
- hostname: host1

Machine 2 (GUI):

- user: user2
- hostname: host2

Start the simulation on machine 1:

- $ ign gazebo -v 4 shapes.sdf -s

Set environment variable and start GUI on machine 2:

- $ export IGN_PARTITION=host1:user1
   - $ ign gazebo -v 4 -g

The default setting for UDS multicast works for me (see [IGN_DISCOVERY_MULTICAST_IP](https://gazebosim.org/api/transport/11.0/envvars.html)).

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [civcode](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/155326/civcode/) with karma: 26 on 2023-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1